# Passing User input references to another class in another file Python

Tags: python, file, class, parameter-passing, user-input

My project said to "Implement the class for the display of the amplitude of the wave file or frequency entered and create the method that will extract a portion of the waveform to display."  I am having trouble passing the user input from one file to another without importing the entire file (tried that gave me errors)

Here's some of my main file:

```
import tkinter as tk
import winsound
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog``
from tkinter import simpledialog

import Create_Account
import Login_file
import Display_Waveform_Amplitude


class audioFrequencyGUI:
#...... (skipping unimportant code)
    def Play(self, Hz):
        self.play_frequency.config(command = lambda: winsound.Beep(Hz, 500))
    
        #MAIN LOOP
        tk.mainloop()

    def Display_Waveform(self):
        DisplayWindow = Display_Waveform_Amplitude.Display_Waveform_AmplitudeGUI()
        DisplayWindow.amplitude_window.wait_window()
```

Heres Display Waveform File:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Display_Waveform_AmplitudeGUI:
    def __init__(math):
        math.amplitude_window = tk.Tk()
        math.amplitude_window.title("Amplitude Display")
        math.amplitude_window.minsize(width = 500, height = 500)


    def plot_graph(math):
        time = 1/frequency
    
        x = np.arrange(0, time, 0.1)
        y = frequency - 1

        plt.title('Amplitude Waveform: Entering Frequencies')
        plt.xlabel('Time (seconds)')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()
```

I know in my code I haven't passed anything because I simply don't know what to do. I've been moving things around and trying out different things for days.  I just need to know how to pass the frequency from my main file to another file that contains another class and function.  Thank you I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If files are in same folder
I think you can solve this just importing the class in the main.py file into display file:

```
from main import audioFrequencyGUI
```

Now you can use funcs from main.py file inside display.py